# Scaling of Precision in Measurements as inverse of square root of Mass of Objects involved

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, research-level, quantum-measurements

I am currently reading this article: **Direct observation of deterministic
macroscopic entanglement** *https://science.sciencemag.org/content/372/6542/622*

The line that I am referring to is in the second paragraph of the article and goes as follows:

> Many future applications of quantum technology
> rely heavily on entanglement; that is,
> on the ability to generate strong quantum
> correlations between separate objects. For entanglement
> to be useful, it must be prepared
> efficiently, followed by measurement and control
> with precision that is inversely proportional
> to the square root of the masses of the
> objects involved

Why is this the case that we need precision that is inversely proportional to square root of masses? Is there any underlying physical reason or is it just an experimental requirement/convention?

At first I thought it might have something to do with $E = mC^2 = \hbar \nu$  with noise spectral densities being inversely proportional to $\nu$ and hence to $m$. But I don't see the square root part. And my reasoning is also very rough and perhaps even in accurate.